# when we use return statement inside if block why compiler not giving any error?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to understand why java compiler not giving any error for code 1. As in code 1, there is no chance of executing line 2 at run-time. is compiler not validating if condition ?
And why it is giving error on code 2.

Code 1 :

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        m1();
     }
     
     public static String m1() {
         if(true){
             System.out.println("if");
             return ""; //line 1
         } else {
             System.out.println("else"); // line 2
             return "";
         }
     }
}
```

Code 2 :

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        m1();
     }
     
     public static String m1() {
         return "";
         System.out.println("last statement"); //compile error : unreachable statement
     }
     
}
```

Comment: code2 is rather obvious: nothing after the return statement can be executed. For code1 i would guess that the compiler is not evaluating the condition, even if it could easily be done for a constant value like that

Comment: [Google search strategy used to find similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+if+else+does+not+cause+unreachable+statement+site:stackoverflow.com)